# Send notification from C# to web Cause Error Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service

Tags: c#, firebase, cloud, messaging

I am trying to send notification to my web app using Firebase. I successfully followed the steps mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?authuser=3) to setup a JavaScript Firebase Cloud Messaging client app. Then successfully I got user approval and subscription token. Here is the code

```
subscribeToNotifications() {
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function () {
      console.log('have permission');
      return messaging.getToken();
    })
    .then(function(token){
      console.warn('Messaging Token: ' + token)
    })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      })
}
```

Then I am trying to use this token to send notification from my C# console. So, here is what I did so far:

**First**: I generated a private key file for my service account following these steps

1. In the Firebase console, open Settings > Service Accounts.
2. Click Generate New Private Key, then confirm by clicking Generate Key.
3. Securely store the JSON file containing the key.

**Second**: I created a .net core C# console app and did the following to initialize firebase.

1. Installed the firebase admin package
   Install-Package FirebaseAdmin -Version 1.8.0
2. Wrote the following code to initialize the firebase app

   ```
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
           {
               Credential = 
               GoogleCredential.FromFile("D:\\__\\myprojectcred.json"),
           });

           Console.WriteLine("Initialized");    
           SendMessageAsync().Wait();    
       }
   ```

The application successfully initialized.

However, when I tried to send the message by calling SendMessageAsync it fails in this line

```
string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
```

The code is as follow:

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SendMessageAsync()
        {
            // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
            var registrationToken = "eRXeB4adi0k:APA91HGlcqh8Ow…nlrO8";
            // See documentation on defining a message payload.
            var message = new Message()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "score", "850" },
                        { "time", "2:45" },
                    },
                Token = registrationToken,

            };

            // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
            // registration token.
            string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
            // Response is a message ID string.
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
        }
```

The error is

> FirebaseMessagingException: Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service

Please help to figure out the problem.

**Update:**
The notification is sent to the server successfully when I tested it with Firefox client, so now the problem is with Edge browser only.